# Считывание чисел из файла в заданном диапазоне

Tags: python, python-3.x, числа

Есть .txt файл с 100 числами. Для работы, мне нужно использовать только первые 50, а остальные мне для работы не нужны.

**Как считать файл, взяв только 50 чисел из 100, и выполнять дальнейший действия с данным диапазоном?**

Comment: Вариант, создать новый файл с нужными числами, не подойдет!

Comment: Считать числа в список, взять первые 50 чисел, делать с ними все, что захочется.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from re import findall
file = open('file.txt', 'r')
nums = findall('\d+', file.read())[:50]
file.close()

# Если в файле есть отрицательные числа то '-?\d+'
# Если нужны не только целые то '-?\d+\.?\d*'
```

Comment: А как же закрывать файл? Мне кажется, что не хватает `with` или `.close()` :)

Comment: @gil9red Зануда ))))

Comment: `with open('file.txt', 'r') as f: nums = findall('\d+', f.read())[:50]` :)

Comment: @gil9red, согласен, так кошерней )